# Identifying the conic $x^2 -2xy +y^2 -5\sqrt{2}x+3\sqrt{2}y+10 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have to identify which conic is:

$$x^2 -2xy +y^2 -5\sqrt{2}x+3\sqrt{2}y+10 = 0$$

The method my book uses is by translation and rotation. It basically proves that if we want to translate na equation

$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

Then, we can set $D = 0$ and $E=0$. If there is a translation that will do it, then, it has to satisfy:

$$Ah + \frac{B}{2}k + \frac{D}{2} = 0$$
$$\frac{B}{2}h + Ck + \frac{E}{2} = 0$$

If you find a solution, then the new equation of the translated conic is:

$$Au^2 + Buv + Cv^2 + \frac{D}{2}h + \frac{E}{2}k + F = 0$$
*as you can see, $A, B$ and $C$ are not affected by rotation
which was translated by $h$ in the x axis, and $k$ in the y axis.

Then, in order to eliminate the $uv$ term, called $B$, the book also proves that if we want to rotate the conic, we can set $B=0$ and then find the necessary angle $\theta$ that will do it. The new equation should be:

$$A't^2 + C'w^2 + \frac{D}{2}h + \frac{E}{2}k + F = 0$$

where

$$A' + C' = A + C$$
$$A'-C' = \frac{B}{\sin(2\theta)}$$

We can find $$\sin(2\theta)$$ by the relation:

$$cotg(2\theta) = \frac{a-c}{b}$$ and then use some trig identities to find $\sin(2\theta)$

As you can see, I rotated the equation where $E = 0$ and $F = 0$. If we couldn't zero out these coefficients, we would have to rotate the original equation, to get:

$$A'x^2 + C'y^2 + (D\cos\theta + E\sin\theta) + (-D\sin\theta + E\sin\theta) + F$$

(as you can see, the independente term is not affected by rotation, and the terms A' and C' can be found the same way as in the last equation)

I think I'm too sleepy, because my conic has no solution to translation, and when I rotate I get:

$$u^2 + v^2 -2u + 8v +10 = 0$$

which is not the answer... Maybe somebody could help me :)

Here's the answer

[image]
It looks like the exercise translated to $V$, but this point does not satisfies any of the two equations. So, neither $E$ or $D$ are $0$ :( I can't understand

Comment: If you're conic has no solution to translation, it's parabola or it's degenerate form.

Comment: By no solution I mean no translation can cancel both linear terms.

Comment: @frank000 it's a parabola, but in my answer the Picture of the equation has translation and rotation :(

Comment: You can still translate to cancel one linear term.

Comment: @frank000 how would it work? ps: i updated with the answer

Comment: I posted an anwser.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start check $\Delta=B^2-4AC$. $\Delta>0$: hyperbobla or the degenerate forms. $\Delta=0$: parabola or the degenerate forms. $\Delta<0$: ellipse, circle or the degenerate forms.

If $\Delta=0$ you cannot cancel both term by translation. You can start by rotation, rotate the axes by $\theta$, we have the new coordinate $(u,v)=(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta,-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$ or $(x,y)=(u\cos\theta-v\sin\theta,v\sin\theta+u\cos\theta)$

From the criteria of canceling $xy$ term you already know $\theta=\pi/4$, we have $(x,y)=(\frac{u-v}{\sqrt2},\frac{u+v}{\sqrt2})$. The conic becomes $\frac{u^2-2uv+v^2+2v^2-2u^2+u^2+2uv+v^2}{2}-5(u-v)+3(u+v)+10=0$
$$v^2-u+4v+5=0$$

Now translate it to cancel the linear $v$ term. This can be done by solving equation, or alternatively, complete the square.
$$u-1=(v+2)^2$$, let $t=u-1$, $w=v+2$ which means move the origin from $(0,0)$ to $(1,-2)$

$$t=w^2$$

Comment: I made new computations, I forgot to rewrite the terms $a$ and $c$ in my equations. Now I computed them but I didn't get $2v^2$ and $0u^2$ as you got. Could you follow my method to verify what's wrong? http://bit.ly/1yEbN7d

Comment: Looks like you have $A'+C'=A+C=2$, $A'-C'=B/sin(\pi/2)=B=-2$ so you should get $A'=0$, $C'=2$.

Comment: I was using $\sin\theta$ and not $\sin 2\theta$ thank you so much